# Valgrind: Where is my memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am working on a rather chaotic library (client/server application) which has a memory leak somewhere, but I cannot find where.

When I start the library and let it do its work, I get the following memory usage using `top` when it finished:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND            
21010 root      20   0  111m  12m 6836 S  0.0  0.7   0:29.20 myapp
21008 root      20   0  172m  99m 6480 S  0.0  5.8   0:14.39 myapp
```

The first line is the client, the second the server.
I let valgrind execute the server and got the following result:

```
==20904== 
==20904== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20904==     in use at exit: 4,723,124 bytes in 199 blocks
==20904==   total heap usage: 40,423,345 allocs, 40,423,146 frees, 1,977,998,844 bytes allocated
==20904== 
==20904== LEAK SUMMARY:
==20904==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20904==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20904==      possibly lost: 914 bytes in 18 blocks
==20904==    still reachable: 4,722,210 bytes in 181 blocks
==20904==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20904== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==20904== 
==20904== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==20904== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2) Killed
```

If I understand this correctly, valgrind says that the server has just about 4,7M of memory still allocated with no real leaks.
It can be that there are no "real" leaks, but normally the library should at this state have freed all resources. I cannot see any part in the code where something is not freed.

How can I find out where the resources are still allocated?

Comment: Use `--leak-check=full` as suggested by valgrind. However, valgrind says you do not have a traditional memory leak. You just have  4MB that has not been released when you exit your app.

Comment: I did, but as far as I can see this just tells me about "possible" leak of the above 1MB, or am I wrong?

Comment: Then run with the --show-reachable=yes

Comment: I exited the App with CTRL+C when it was in the state that it was finished (and with 100MB RAM usage). I thought it would then show results for the allocated 100MB

Comment: No, it will not. Memory you request (with e.g. malloc()) might never be returned to the OS, even if your free() it, until your app exits. You can have 100MB assigned to your process without your app actually using it. The malloc subsystem often keeps the memory around for future re-use, and rarly, if ever, returns it back to the OS.

Comment: So how can I find out whether there are e.g. undestroyed objects that are only destroyed on app exit or it is just memory that is not returned to the OS?

Comment: It says in the valgrind output. You have no leaked memory, but 914 bytes that's possibly leaked(likely that's memory allocated by some libraries that valgrind weren't able to figure out). You have 4MB that's still allocated (And those 4MB are not leaked, as valgrind have found you still have poointers to that memory). Valgrind does that check after any exit handlers were run (which e.g. would destroy global c++ objects)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a brute-force method and print to a log file before each allocation and after each delete.

You may want to print the object's size (or the size allocated) and maybe the name of the object.

You are looking for matching pairs, allocation and deallocation.

You may also want to print out the invocation number which will help match, i.e. if there are 4 invocations of allocation, you should be able to find deallocation #3 to match with allocation #3.

This requires careful inspection of the code to verify that all allocations have been identified.